# App crashes when trying to connect to Neura service

Tags: android, neura

I use Neura services for my app. After installing the service,
the app crashed when I got to the screen of the authentication.Sometimes those crashes happened when I was just opening the application.

Here is the exception message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean com.intel.aware.csp.jni.AwareNative.isAvailable(int) (tried Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNative_isAvailable and Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNative_isAvailable__I)
    at com.intel.aware.csp.jni.AwareNative.isAvailable(Native Method)
    at com.intel.aware.csp.datalooper.DataNodeAwareNative.available(SourceFile:70)
    at com.intel.aware.csp.datalooper.DataLooper.a(SourceFile:89)
    at com.intel.aware.csp.datalooper.StepCounterDataLooper.a(SourceFile:57)
    at com.intel.aware.csp.datalooper.DataLooper.start(SourceFile:335)
    at com.intel.context.provider.c.o.a.start(SourceFile:61)
    at com.intel.context.provider.c.a(SourceFile:48)
    at com.intel.context.provider.d.a(SourceFile:303)
    at com.intel.context.core.LocalService.enableProvider(SourceFile:92)
    at com.intel.context.Sensing.enableSensing(SourceFile:206)
    at com.neura.android.service.IntelSensingService.startSensingContextType(IntelSensingService.java:350)
    at com.neura.android.service.IntelSensingService.startSensingPedometer(IntelSensingService.java:331)
    at com.neura.android.service.IntelSensingService.handleStartCommandWithSensingServiceReady(IntelSensingService.java:515)
    at com.neura.android.service.IntelSensingService.access$300(IntelSensingService.java:52)
    at com.neura.android.service.IntelSensingService$5.run(IntelSensingService.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And the error from logcat:

```
06-01 14:16:52.605 25852-25958/com.bitbite E/art: No implementation found for int[] com.intel.aware.csp.jni.AwareNativeHelper.poll(int[]) (tried Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNativeHelper_poll and Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNativeHelper_poll___3I)
06-01 14:16:52.605 25852-25958/com.bitbite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: poller
Process: com.bitbite, PID: 25852
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int[] com.intel.aware.csp.jni.AwareNativeHelper.poll(int[]) (tried Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNativeHelper_poll and Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNativeHelper_poll___3I)
at com.intel.aware.csp.jni.AwareNativeHelper.poll(Native Method)
at com.intel.aware.csp.datalooper.DataPoller$1.run(SourceFile:84)
06-01 14:16:52.606 25852-25956/com.bitbite E/art: No implementation found for boolean com.intel.aware.csp.jni.AwareNative.isAvailable(int) (tried Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNative_isAvailable and Java_com_intel_aware_csp_jni_AwareNative_isAvailable__I)
06-01 14:16:52.607 25852-25956/com.bitbite I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25852 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have done to solve this. We are not your code monkeys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can do :

1. Clean and rebuild your project
2. Contact intel support for this issue (even though you're using library that uses intel sdk and it's not actual your issue.
   [intel idk forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/context-sensing-sdk)
3. Check your main gradle definitions - intel sdk can only work with gradle 1.3.1 and below, known error.

your classpath should be :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
}
```